# Retention Insights not working

Tags: facebook-insights

Is there any reason my Users Gone Stale , Users Revived and Users Retained insights would stop dead all on the same day?  They have not reported back for 11 days now and I dont understand why?

Comment: does this question have anything to do with programming or software development ?

Comment: I am not sure Sreenath, as I am not a programmer or developer? Does your response answer my question? IF you are suggesting this is not the place to raise such a question, then please advise where you think it should be raised?

Comment: Sorry for that snidey comment :D. Hey there's something called http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ , but since this is not a programming related question it might not evoke any response over there either. I think http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is the appropriate forum for this.

Comment: Hi Sreenath, thanks for the advice, sorry for my pointed response, I understand this is mainly a techie related forum, however had no where else to ask this question